# Создание уникального ID при добавлении закладок в базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

**Вступление:**

Переменная `'".crc32('$urlpage')."' + '$session->id'"` в запросе MySQL была создана для того чтобы ID закладки не совпадал с ID закладками других пользователей с таким же именем.  Я знаю, что проблема именно в этой переменной, так как я только учусь, не знаю как решить эту проблему.  Проблема в том, что он пытается записать в одну и ту же строку в базе данных c хешированным URL с прибавлением (+) ID пользователя.

Переменная `$urlpage` работают правильно отображает название текущей страницы там где она прописана и переменная `$session->id` тоже работает правильно выводит ID авторизированного пользователя.

Переменные `$timestamp` и `$timestamp` работают правильно и записывают данные в базу правильно.

**Структура таблицы `links`**

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(9) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Индексы таблицы `links`**

```
ALTER TABLE `links`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**addbookmark.php**

```php
   <?php
    $titlename = 'Название сервиса';
    // Автоматическое определение URL текущей страницы (работает правильно)
    $urlpage = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 's' : '') . '://';
    $urlpage = $urlpage . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    define('URL', $urlpage);

    $date = date_create(); $timestamp = date_timestamp_get($date);

    // Функция добавления закладки в базу данных (работает все кроме '".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id')
    if (isset($_POST['submitlink'])){
        $sqlbk = "INSERT IGNORE INTO links (id, name, url, date, user_id)
        VALUES ('".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id', '$titlename', '$urlpage', '$timestamp', '$session->id')
        on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id'";
        $result = $db->prepare($sqlbk);
        $result->execute();
        if ($result) {
          echo "<p>Добавлена в закладки</p>";
        } else {
          echo 'Произошла ошибка при добавлении закладки'; }

    }
    ?>

    <!-- Форма для добавления текущей страницу в базу данных -->
    <form method="POST" action="" class="ui form">
        <button class="ui basic button" name="submitlink" type="submit" value="1"><i class="file outline icon"></i>Добавить текущую страницу в закладки</button>
    </form>
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

В базу данных должно записываться закладки с уникальным ID для каждого пользователя.

**Проблема:**

Переменная `'".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id'` записывает id в базу следующим образом:

Для страницы `http://sait.ru/page_one.php` в базе записывает `id` *343242343 + 1 = 343242344*

Для страницы `http://sait.ru/page_two.php` в базе записывает `id` *343242343 + 1 = 343242344*

Для страницы `http://sait.ru/service/index.php` в базе записывает `id` *343242343 + 1 = 343242344*

По задумке переменная должна была записать в базу
Для страницы `http://sait.ru/page_one.php` в базе записать `id` *1060205147 + 1 = 1060205148*

Для страницы `http://sait.ru/page_two.php` в базе записать `id` *880931229 + 1 = 880931230*

Для страницы `http://sait.ru/service/index.php` в базе записать `id` *2968828718 + 1 = 2968828719*

Comment: `".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id'` как написано так и записывает. в чем вопрос-то, разъясните?

Comment: Когда закладка добавляется в таблицу `links` в параметр `id` записывается Хешированная сумма URL страницы с помощью `'".crc32('$urlpage')."'` чтобы каждый пользователь не перезаписывал со своим ID тот же параметр к нему прибавляется число пользователя с помощью переменной `'$session->id'` для создания уникально ID для каждого пользователя.
Но в данном случае когда в запросе к переменной `'".crc32('$urlpage')."'` плюсуется (+) переменная `'$session->id'` он начинает записывать в базу один и тот же ID хотя адрес URL разные.

Comment: а составной ключ/уникальный индекс на link/id чем вас не утроил? подразумевая, что про auto_increment вы знаете. Зачем вообще это все у вас тут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут несколько раз посоветовали атрибут AUTO_INCREMENT, но для моей задумки он не подходит. Решил проблему иначе, как говорится "Всё гениальное - просто". Создал переменную `$crcurlbk = crc32("$urlpage");` и в запросе в базу данных поменял `'".crc32('$urlpage')."'+'$session->id'` на `'$crcurlbk'+'$session->id'` и всё заработало. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 1):

Для таблицы links, столбца id должно быть проставлено AUTO_INCREMENT

Тогда каждый раз при добавлении новой записи ID будет увеличиваться на 1.

Если я правильно вас понял :)